# how to force browser to go to server side instead of getting data from broswer cache

Tags: asp.net, firefox, browser-cache

the problem is the firefox is showing "document expired" on clicking back button. Is there any way to re-request data?

I read on msdn : If you pass either NoCache or ServerAndNoCache to the SetCacheability method to prevent a requesting browser from caching a page in its History folder, any time a user clicks a back or forward button, a new version of the response will be requested.

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

I dont know how to use this in codebehind or will this be helpful.?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up expirations and caching in IIS if you want to handle it for the entire site, but otherwise doing it on `Page_Load` might be too late in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

If you use FF:

- open new page "about:config"
- find parameter network.http.use-cache
- toggle it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply these `<meta>` tags in the `<head>` section of the `HTML` document.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <!-- no cache headers -->
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content=" no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="no-cache">
    <!-- end no cache headers -->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <!-- Body Here -->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Reference: [How to prevent caching in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067)